# diagnostic Collect Stats recommendations already implemented

Tags: teradata

Why does `diagnostic helpstats on for session; explain sql` recommend collection of statistics I'm already collecting?  Sometimes it's cleared the next time I run the explain, other times it isn't, even when I collect them again from the explain text.

Is it caching recommendations somewhere?  Do I need to clear something before running the `Explain` again?

thx for any help,

-Beth

Comment: Its not the recommended 'additional' statistics, these are total recommended stats that may help the query parser, regardless of whether they are present right now or not

Comment: @xenodevil, if that were the case, I would expect recommendations to always be the same, but most of the time, they're cleared after I collect the stats.